Smarty $template_dir Protected Property problem on upgrade from 5.73.4 to 5.74.0
Running CiviCRM on Joomla 3.10.12 I'm trying to upgrade from CiviCRM 5.73.4 to 5.74.0 and upwards for a client. I've upgraded it from 5.2.1 through to 5.73.4 so far. Its on localhost XAMPP, PHP 8.10. The error I am seeing is

Cannot access protected property Smarty\Smarty::$template_dir

I'm good with Joomla stuff but not so much with CiviCRM. I can see from the settings files its running Smarty 5. Any assistance appreciated.

Turns out this was due to a CiviCRM extension that was very old. Disabling it and then uninstalling it solved. First we rolled back a version to access CiviCRM, then we uninstalled the extension 'Bootstrap layout for civisualize'.

I have the same problem, how did you find uut which extension was the culprit?

Same situation here... Can anyone let us know what extension was the issue, or how to track down the issue?

I don't have Bootstrap layout for civisualize installed, so wondering how we track down which extension might be causing the issue. Nothing in civi logs to shed any light on this either...

I am in the process of the same issue.  Unfortunately it seems that the only way I could track the issue down was to do a fresh install and then enable the extensions one by one... Start by ensuring all extensions are updated.  Then do any extensions you have written yourself (embarrasing...) I also had an issue with NotesPermission, Shoreditch and CiviCRM config,

Meant to add the reason for the install one by one is that if it affects more than one extension, you'll see what particulat extension is the issue from the displayed error, but of course, it will fail again on the next one after you fix that.

If it helps anyone else, I had to remove an older ShoreDitch and TheIsland theme. I also uinstalled com.cividesk.l10n.update-master and replaced it with the upland extension. If I can track it down to one of those three, I'll update here.

Another thing have discoverved, is if I set Joomla error messages to maximum, and then go to the civiCRM dashboard (without having upgraded), I see on screen a list of the extensions that trigger the error. So from there I was able to check which ones had updates and in my case, a few custom extensions that required modification.

The extension is mentioned in the error backtrace. Most of the time, the second or third line.
